# How to execute arbitrary command under `bash -c`

Tags: bash

What is a procedure to decorate an arbitrary bash command to execute it in a subshell?  I cannot change the command, I have to decorate it on the outside.

the best I can think of is

```
>bash -c '<command>'
```

works on these:

```
>bash -c 'echo'
>bash -c 'echo foobar'
>bash -c 'echo \"'
```

but what about the commands such as

```
echo \'
```

and especially

```
echo \'\"
```

The decoration has to be always the same for all commands. It has to always work.

Comment: How is this `<command>` provided? Contained in a file, in a shell variable. I.e. if you are building a function "execute arbitrary command with bash -c", what are the arguments?

Comment: Replacing all single quotes with `'\''` makes the resulting string safe for use inside single quotes but I'm not sure if that answers the question.

Comment: @EtanReisner  maybe...  are you sure that such a replacement will never change the result of any shell command, ever?

Comment: @PawelVeselov  there is a shell script in an editor, on each line is a command.  I have to automatically edit the script, to surround each line with "something" so that it executes in a subshell

Comment: Subshell, or separate process?  Just putting parentheses around it will make it a subshell:  `x=1; (x=2; echo $x); echo $x` outputs 2 and then 1

Comment: @MarkReed  well, what I want, is to insulate from any problem that a command has, for example, if it exits in such a way that the whole script exits, or terminal disappears, I don't want that.  If a command dies and does something horrible, I want to go on and continue with the next command.

Comment: @MarkReed  this looks like it is working, make it an answer!

Comment: `bash -c` creates a new process that is a shell; however, it **is not** a subshell, which is a shell instance created by a fork() with no exec().

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you Charles, yes I need to learn proper terminology in this area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say "subshell" - you can get one of those by just putting parentheses around the command:

```
x=outer
(x=inner; echo "x=$x"; exit)
echo "x=$x"
```

produces this:

```
x=inner
x=outer
```

Answer (score 1):

You could (ab)use heredocs:

```
bash -c "$(cat <<-EOF
    echo \'\"
EOF
)"
```

Comment: Hmm, somehow a complex command that was failing, after being treated this way, succeeds

Comment: Perfect.  Just what I was looking for.  When I do `bash <<HEREDOC` it doesn't print the same way as when I run with `bash -c`. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way without using -c option:

```
bash <<EOF
echo \'\"
EOF
```

Comment: Same as to another answer - a command that failed before, suddenly passes and does not complain, not good

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is exactly the same as `escapeshellcmd()` in PHP (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.escapeshellcmd.php)

You just need to escape #&;`|*?~<>^()[]{}$\, \x0A and \xFF. ' and " are escaped only if they are not paired.

But beware of security issues...

Answer (score 0):

Let bash take care of it this way:

1) prepare the command as an array:

```
astrCmd=(echo \'\");
```

2) export the array as a simple string:

```
export EXPORTEDastrCmd="`declare -p astrCmd| sed -r "s,[^=]*='(.*)',\1,"`";
```

3) restore the array and run it as a full command:

```
bash -c "declare -a astrCmd='$EXPORTEDastrCmd';\${astrCmd[@]}"
```

Create a function to make these steps more easy like:

```
FUNCbash(){ 
  astrCmd=("$@");
  export EXPORTEDastrCmd="`declare -p astrCmd| sed -r "s,[^=]*='(.*)',\1,"`";
  bash -c "declare -a astrCmd='$EXPORTEDastrCmd';\${astrCmd[@]}";
}
FUNCbash echo \'\"
```